# How to optimize INSERT and UPDATE on 10M records in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables - `accounts`, `inf_accounts`. There is a daily update on millions of rows from `inf_accounts` to `accounts`.

First I do INSERT of records not included in `accounts` table:

```
INSERT INTO accounts SELECT * FROM inf_accounts ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
```

then I do UPDATE on records with a different `account_status`:

```
UPDATE accounts acc SET account_status=inf.account_status FROM inf_accounts inf WHERE acc.account_number=inf.account_number AND acc.account_status<>inf.account_status;
```

and last I do DELETE on inf_account:

```
DELETE FROM inf_accounts;
```

It works kind of 'a ok', but I wonder if there is a way to optimize it by running UPDATE first, then DELETE on UPDATED records and then do INSERT on the rest of those records since INSERT right now is unnecessarily being run on all the records. But all I was able to create was absolutely horrible in context of performance.

See DELETE nr. 1:

```
EXPLAIN DELETE FROM inf_accounts i USING accounts a WHERE a.account_number = i.account_number;

Delete on inf_accounts i  (cost=427341.04..950096.91 rows=0 width=0)
->  Hash Join  (cost=427341.04..950096.91 rows=9885646 width=12)
    Hash Cond: (a.account_number = i.account_number)
    ->  Seq Scan on accounts a  (cost=0.00..320884.95 rows=10035395 width=23)
    ->  Hash  (cost=245846.46..245846.46 rows=9885646 width=23)
          ->  Seq Scan on inf_accounts i  (cost=0.00..245846.46 rows=9885646 width=23)
JIT:
  Functions: 10
"  Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true"
```

and DELETE nr. 2:

```
EXPLAIN DELETE FROM inf_accounts i WHERE i.account_number IN (SELECT i.account_number FROM inf_accounts i LEFT JOIN accounts a on a.account_number = i.account_number);

Delete on inf_accounts i  (cost=1141245.48..1817659.09 rows=0 width=0)
->  Hash Semi Join  (cost=1141245.48..1817659.09 rows=9885646 width=18)
    Hash Cond: (i.account_number = i_1.account_number)
    ->  Seq Scan on inf_accounts i  (cost=0.00..245846.46 rows=9885646 width=23)
    ->  Hash  (cost=950096.91..950096.91 rows=9885646 width=29)
          ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=427341.04..950096.91 rows=9885646 width=29)
                Hash Cond: (a.account_number = i_1.account_number)
                ->  Seq Scan on accounts a  (cost=0.00..320884.95 rows=10035395 width=23)
                ->  Hash  (cost=245846.46..245846.46 rows=9885646 width=23)
                      ->  Seq Scan on inf_accounts i_1  (cost=0.00..245846.46 rows=9885646 width=23)
```

Is there a way to do it better or do I have to stick with the original INSERT first approach?

Answer (score 0):

The `INSERT` and the `UPDATE` could be a single operation:

```
INSERT INTO accounts
SELECT * FROM inf_accounts
ON CONFLICT (account_number) DO UPDATE
SET account_status = EXCLUDED.account_status;
```

You need a unique constraint on `account_number` for that.